# Conda error usage and unable to reinstall it

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have an issue with `conda`. I cant use it so I want to reinstall it. I get the following error as soon as I try to use it.

```
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.
```

Also I followed the instructions but still it seems it uses another conda (not standalone version). So that's why I want to reinstall everything. The problem is that I cannot delete the following conda versions from dist-packages.

```
Requirement already satisfied: conda in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (4.3.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pycosat>=0.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from conda) (0.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml>=0.11.14 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from conda) (0.17.21)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.12.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from conda) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.2.6; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version < "3.11" in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from ruamel.yaml>=0.11.14->conda) (0.2.6)
```

if I use `rm -rf conda` to remove it, but I get the following error.

```
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/binstar.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__pycache__/requirements.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__pycache__/notebook.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__pycache__/binstar.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__pycache__/yaml_file.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/notebook.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/yaml_file.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/__init__.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/specs/requirements.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_remove.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_upload.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_remove.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_create.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/common.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_list.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_attach.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_update.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_export.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__pycache__/main_upload.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_update.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_list.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_attach.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/common.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_export.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/__init__.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/cli/main_create.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/exceptions.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/yaml.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/env.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/compat.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/exceptions.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__pycache__/pip_util.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/pip_util.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/env.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/yaml.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/notebooks.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/__pycache__/notebooks.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/__pycache__/uploader.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/uploader.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/utils/__init__.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/__init__.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/compat.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/__pycache__/pip.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/__pycache__/conda.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/__pycache__/base.cpython-38.pyc': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/conda.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/pip.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/base.py': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove 'conda_env/installers/__init__.py': Permission denied
```

Apparently I do not have permission to delete the files.
Moreover, I tried to use `pip uninstall conda` and I get the following:

```
Found existing installation: conda 4.3.16
Uninstalling conda-4.3.16:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/conda
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/conda-4.3.16.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/conda/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/conda_env/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-yej0ctsl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 78, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 687, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 334, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 809, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 718, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 675, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 673, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'conda'
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you tried ``pip uninstall conda``?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made an update in my question about that. Still doesn't work, no permission.

Comment: Then you should try ``sudo pip uninstall conda``. And install packages in further only while in [virtuelenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest).

Comment: This seems to work. I don't have conda in my path anymore. The problem is now that I want to download ``conda`` as a standalone application from miniconda, I follow the instructions from https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html there is no ``bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`` to run

Comment: That's the different question, I guess you need to download that file first. As for now, you should close the question if it's solved.

Comment: I recommend [`micromamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/micromamba.html) for proper standalone Conda environment manipulation.